# Testing a spam filter

Tags: spam, test

We are testing a new gateway and spam filter infrastructure. In addition to redirecting some accounts I would like to "publish" a test address (corti@test.id.ethz.ch) to attract spam.

Is there a way to distribute an email address as honeypot for spammers?

Comment: Post it online?  That's how they get everyone else's address..

Comment: Yes, the question is rather where.

Comment: I edited the question, but it shows that abusing server fault to publish the address is not ideal. And other public services would feel the same ...

Comment: Online was the answer.  Post it wide and post it far.  Until it gets into one of the lists that get resold over and over and over again you're going to sit around waiting.  If there was a single place you could put an address that they'd pick up for this purpose that would quickly become a source they start to ignore.  There are other ways to test your setup than this way.  Take existing spam messages, change them, send them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [unsubscribe link](http://www.eyefrom.top/c_unsub.php?o=efnm381) with your test email address. These people are the biggest spammers I know about, I'm sure you'll get 100's of spam emails everyday in a matter of weeks.